# calcular horas nocturnas (6pm-6am)entre dos fechas en oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

quisiera saber como puedo calcular las horas nocturnas 6pm - 6am entre dos fechas, por ejemplo si tengo las fechas 19-06-2019 8:00PM y 20-06-2019 8:00pm el calculo me debería dar 12 horas que corresponden a 10 horas de 8pm del día 19 a 6am del día 20 más 2 horas que corresponde de 6pm del día 20 a 8pm del día 20, este calculo lo debo hacer en oracle. estaría muy agradecido si me ayudan con  esto.